# Image appears after checking checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        imgPurple.Visible = true;
    }
```

For now, I am able to make the imgPurple appear after I click btnSubmit. However, thats not what I want.

I want the imgPurple to appear when I check a checkbox, not button. How do I achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898168/how-to-check-if-a-checkboxes-state-has-changed

Comment: Sorry, did not really answer my question :/

Comment: What language are you using? C#? Also Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I am currently using HTML :)

Comment: This looks like C#. If so the @MMD suggestion is correct. Add a checkbox and us OnCheckedChanged

Comment: Try with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: how to use javascript and jquery for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have AutoPostBack set to true? The button you have tried will cause a postback but a checkbox change won't postback by default. This works:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
```

With the following:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgPurple.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Also worth noting whilst your final output is html, your working in C# and ASP.net. If you tag both of them in future questions you may get a quicker response. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in C# or .NET(If that's even the language it is), but if you compare the previous values with the current values and they are not the same, then they have changed.

So save the previous state into an object, and compare that object with the current state.

Another note, since you're not using a button as the event target, you'll probably want to use something like @Bobney was suggesting as the event handler like OnCheckedChanged as opposed to BtnSubmit_Click.

Comment: I have tried using OnCheckChanged but I could not get it to work still. Im not sure why btnSubmit is able to do it but Checkbox can't

Comment: Are you sure you're using HTML? If you are then none of this will work and you need to be implementing the functionality you're looking for with CSS or JS. Can you edit your post and add your full code?

Comment: I am using HTML. This is for my ASP.NET page in HTML for visual studio

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah I'm sorry I haven't worked in Visual Studio in 10+ years. I didn't even realize you could use HTML with .NET in VS. Good Luck, Hopefully you'll figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

HTML with JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showPic()
{
    if (document.getElementById("myCb").checked === true)
    {
        //document.getElementById("myPic").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("myPic").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else
    {
        //document.getElementById("myPic").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myPic").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showPic();">

<input id="myCb" type="checkbox" onclick="showPic();" /><br />
<br /> 
<img id="myPic" src="myPic.png" alt="myPic" />

</body>
</html>
```